# Event Receivers in Sharepoint 2010 to capture attachment

Tags: sharepoint, sharepoint-2010

I would like to capture attachments in a list item to check file length and its extensions. I created an SPItemEventReceiver class and the SPItemEventReceiver.ItemAttachmentAdding method was overridden. However the event is not firing when an attachment is added.

When this event will be fired? What can I do to check the files length and extentions?

**My EventHandler class:**

```
public class EventReceiver : SPItemEventReceiver
{
   /// <summary>
   /// An attachment is being added to the item.
   /// </summary>
   public override void ItemAttachmentAdding(SPItemEventProperties properties)
   {

       //some code here

       base.ItemAttachmentAdding(properties);
   }
}
```

**My Element.xml**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<Elements xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/sharepoint/">
  <Receivers ListTemplateId="100">
      <Receiver>
        <Name>EventReceiverItemAttachmentAdding</Name>
        <Type>ItemAttachmentAdding</Type>
        <Assembly>$SharePoint.Project.AssemblyFullName$</Assembly>
        <Class>EventReceiver.EventReceiver</Class>
        <SequenceNumber>10000</SequenceNumber>
      </Receiver>
  </Receivers>
</Elements>
```

Comment: How did you associate the Event Receiver class with your list?

Comment: I just created the elements.xml as shown above.

Comment: Ok. You might also want to expand on "some code here." What does your code do that tells you whether or not it is working? Also, based on your elements file, this receiver will be attached to all Custom Lists. Do you have code that checks which list raised the event?

Comment: That is exactly the problem, does not matter what means "some code here", because the code never run there. Maybe I misunderstood when this event will be fired, but I’d like the receive a event when some attaches a file to a item list.

Comment: How have you proved the code is not running?

Comment: First I created others events in the same class (just to check it). I set the project as "Start up Project" and then I debugged the code. All others events have been fired, but ItemAttachmentAdding.